# learnpythonthehardway exercise 21 write out a formula

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to solve the math problem in exercise 21 in Q&A, `24 + 34 / 100 - 1023`.
using functions:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADD %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACT %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDE %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b

print "Solve 24 + 34 / 100 - 1023?"
what = subtract(add(24, divide(34,100)),1023)

print "The Answer is", what
```

the answer I got is -999
but when I do on calculator I got = -998.66

how to get the answer with decimal?

Comment: To make division work properly in Python 2.x you need to `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `float` values , not `integers`. By doing so:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADD %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return float(a + b) # WE RETURN A FLOAT

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACT %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return float(a - b) # WE RETURN A FLOAT

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDE %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return float(a / b) # WE RETURN A FLOAT

print "Solve 24 + 34 / 100 - 1023?"
what = subtract(add(24, divide(34.0,100)),1023)

print "The Answer is", what
```

You will get the following output:

```
Solve 24 + 34 / 100 - 1023?
DIVIDE 34 / 100
ADD 24 + 0
SUBTRACT 24 - 1023
The Answer is -998.66
```